# huge postgres database size reduction

Tags: postgresql

I have a huge database (9 billon rows, 3000 columns) which is currently host on postgres, it is huge about 30 TB in size. I am wondering if there is some practical ways to reduce the size of the database while preserving the same information in the database, as storage is really costly.

Comment: only preserving the same information (archiving?) or should the database remain operational.

Comment: Have you considered sharding the database using extension like 'citus' and distribute to many nodes?

Comment: Might be better posted on sister site, https://DBA.StackExchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to delete any data.

- Vacuuming. Depending on how many updates/deletes your database performs there will be much garbage. A database that size is likely full of tables that do not cross vacuum thresholds often (pg13 has a fix for this). Manually running vacuums will allocate dead rows for re-use, and free up space where ends of pages are no longer needed.
- Index management. These bloat over time and should be smaller than your tables. Re-indexing (concurrently) will give you some space back, or allow re-use of existing pages.
- data de-duplication / normalisation. See where you can remove data from tables where it is not needed, or presented elsewhere in the database.

Comment: Thanks very much, these strategies might be very useful for a database in operation for a long time. It is actually a big new table of 9 billion rows and 3000 columns, only having 1 index.